# Twitter Bootstrap - Full width background (image)

Tags: html, css, background, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currenly on a project and I'm trying out the awesome Twitter Bootrtrap including the responsive grid. All works fine and dandy except for one issue.

How do you give the `.container` (which holds the grid) a background color? Example:

```
<div class="container green">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <p>This is a test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <p>This is a test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.green{
 background:green;
}
```

When I add a color to the container it will turn green but leaves a margin on the left side, about 20px. How do I implement a full-width background?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That margin you're seeing is due to the fact that the `.row` class part of the grid system removes 20px from the left to accommodate the `span` classes inside each row; that class reads as follows:

```
.row {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

You can circumvent that by just wrapping your `.container` div with another container with the background color of your choice, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="green">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <p>This is a test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <p>This is a test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.green{
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: thx @Andres for the help. This solutions works but this also results in a full background that spans the intire screen instead of only the inner container. I can't wrap the color div with a width atribute becaus the .container is responsive and therefor has a varible width..

Comment: @Michael as the other posted suggested you need to provide more information to your case or a working demo at a site such as http://jsfiddle.net so we can take a look and answer appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}

.container {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: would work but is not an option in my case, this will interfer with other objects in the project.

Comment: How are we supposed to know that based on your provided code? If you have restrictions, they need to be disclosed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its work for me, wrap your code like this.

```
<div class="rowWrp">
    <div class="row colorBg">
        <div class="span6">
            <p>This is a test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS it:

```
.colorBg {
   background:red;
  }

.rowWrp {
  background:red; 
  width:940px; 
  padding-right:20px;
  }
```

Here I assume we use fixed layout.